# Exon skipping in mammals

Tags: molecular-genetics, genomics, splicing

I've heard from several sources that the predominant form of alternative splicing (at least in mammals) is exon skipping. However, my personal evidence is only anecdotal: I've heard it and read it, but have not seen references to literature. Is there a seminal paper or set of papers establishing this finding that I can cite?

Answer (score 2):

You can see [this](http://www.nature.com/nrg/journal/v11/n5/full/nrg2776.html) review.

> There are several different types of alternative splicing (AS) events,
>   which can be classified into four main subgroups. The first type is
>   exon skipping, in which a type of exon known as a cassette exon is
>   spliced out of the transcript together with its flanking introns (see
>   the figure, part a). Exon skipping accounts for nearly 40% of AS
>   events in higher eukaryotes <sup>[17, 111]</sup> but is extremely rare in lower
>   eukaryotes.